# Calculate the length of the longest ordered sub-sequence within the array

Tags: java

I was looking at websites such as https://projecteuler.net/, and I came across this question:

"Given an unordered array of integers of length N > 0, calculate the length of the longest ordered (ascending from left [lower index] to right [higher index]) sub-sequence within the array."

For the live of me I am struggling to find a solution in Java. Can anyone help?

EDIT:

Some examples:

Example 1

Input: [1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 2, 3, 7]
Expected Output: 4

Example 2

Input: [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5]
Expected Output: 3

Example 3

Input: [2, 7, 1, 8, 2, 8, 1]
Expected Output: 2

Comment: Are you sure your examples are correct regarding the expected output? If you are looking for the Longest Increasing Subsequence for which @ILoveCoding answered, expected output for example 1 should be 6 as the biggest increasing sub-sequence is [1,2,3,5,6,7].
Or do you mean increasing continuous subsequence (numbers are in a row?) because this is what your example show.

Comment: When you are referring to ordering how do you deal with equal numbers? For instance in an array [2,2,2,3,4,5], the ordered sub-array length is 6 or 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A term for what you want to find is a subarray, not a subsequence(according to your examples). You can solve it in a linear time using a simple loop:

```
int res = 0;
int cur = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && a[i] <= a[i - 1])
        cur = 0;
    cur++;
    res = Math.max(res, cur);
}
```

Comment: You could also set `res` inside the if block (before `cur = 0`) to avoid the method `Math.max` being called in every iteration. But, yes, this is a very minor improvement.

Comment: I wish there was a spoiler block for the solution since this is from a learning website.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc There is one `>! I'm a Spoiler` (not here in the comment, but you can use this in questions and answers).

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc I guess because the above code is indented (4 whitespace) you have to remove them first. But this will remove the syntax highlighting. And you have to write it on every line.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if equal elements are considered ordered. Also you can `return` if there are not enough elements to create a bigger maxLength.

```
public static int maxLength(int[] array) {
    if (array.length <= 1) return array.length; // check for null also
    int maxLength = 1;
    int curLength = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        //extra check to finish earlier if possible (you may omit it)
        if ((array.length - i + curLength) <= maxLength)
            return maxLength;
        if (array[i] > array[i-1]) //use >= if equal elements count too
            curLength++;
        else {
            if (maxLength < curLength)
                maxLength = curLength;
            curLength = 1;
        }

    }
    //final check (in case the last element is included in maxLength)
    if (maxLength < curLength)
        return curLength;
    return maxLength;
}
```